# how to update a table that used Union

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to update a table that gets result using Select Union of 2 tables:
lets say we have:(using SQL Server)

```
 select something
from table1 join
     table2
     on ??? 
where condition1
union 
select something
from table1 join
     table3
     on ???
where condition2
```

Code

```
    select it.itemid,it.itemgroupid,it.itemtype, it.itemname
    from item it
    left join part r on r.itemid = it.itemid 
    left join SALES sl on it.itemid=sl.itemid
   where
      it.itemtype =1
      and r.partnumber =10
      and sl.CREATEDDATE between '2010-01-01 00:00:00' and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

UNION 
     select distinct it.itemid,it.itemgroupid,it.itemtype, it.itemname
     from item it 
     left join salesdetail sa on sa.itemid=it.itemid 
     it.itemtype =1
     where sa.SALESSTATUS =1
```

`
How can I update a field in table1 that depends on the result of the above Select query ?

I wan now to update the itemTable field x to 1 if the itemid is the same ite id the above select is outputting

Comment: can you put some code that you have?

Comment: do you have primary keys from table1 that are in both queries?

Comment: By writing an update statement maybe ? We need more info on what your problem is

Comment: @Kristjan Kica Yes I do have a primary Key in table1 that is in both queries,

Comment: A `TABLE` can't contain a `UNION`. Is this actually a `VIEW`? Maybe you just need an `UPDATE ...FROM` statement with a subquery or CTE. We don't have enough detail here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `WHERE` clause with `IN` for the update. Be sure to update with name of *some field*. Below uses a CTE as the `IN` query value. All fields have been removed in `SELECT` except *itemid*:

```
WITH cte AS
  (select it.itemid
   from item it
   left join part r on r.itemid = it.itemid 
   left join SALES sl on it.itemid = sl.itemid
   where it.itemtype =1
     and r.partnumber =10
     and sl.CREATEDDATE between '2010-01-01 00:00:00' and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

   union

   select distinct it.itemid
   from item it 
   left join salesdetail sa on sa.itemid = it.itemid 
   where it.itemtype = 1
     and sa.SALESSTATUS =1
  )

UPDATE item it
SET it.<SOME FIELD> = 1
WHERE it.itemid IN cte
```

Comment: I was able to work around the query so i didn't have to use a union which made it easier to update, thanks !

Comment: Do note: you can answer your own question. Curious though, did this solution work as alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try something link this:

```
`UPDATE item SET item_id =
select it.itemid
    from item it
    left join part r on r.itemid = it.itemid 
    left join SALES sl on it.itemid=sl.itemid
   where
      it.itemtype =1
      and r.partnumber =10
      and sl.CREATEDDATE between '2010-01-01 00:00:00' and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

UNION 
     select distinct it.itemid
     from item it 
     left join salesdetail sa on sa.itemid=it.itemid 
     it.itemtype =1
     where sa.SALESSTATUS =1`
```